# How can i get access to a tree view which is placed in a tab contol in c#

Tags: c#

how can i get access to a tree view ,which is placed in a tab contol
i used

```
treeView1.TopNode.Text=filename;
```

for setting the top node name.
but it always shows an error like

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize it with `treeView1 = new TreeView()` and then add elements - you are tyring to set a text of a non-existing element.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode for example.

Comment: I did what you said. But still, it is not working
I am adding treeview1 at the design time. At that time itself I am setting the root

Comment: Check in the debugger if the TopNode is really set.